# react-native issue with installing package (tesseract-ocr)

Tags: react-native, npm, tesseract

I tried to import the package react-native-tesseract-ocr into my react-native project, but I am receiving error: ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

command used for installation:

`npm i react-native-tesseract-ocr`

This is the complete log of the error received.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'i',
0 verbose cli   'react-native-tesseract-ocr'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\MobileDev\EI\ei-platform\EIPlatform\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\aksha\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 13ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 3ms
23 verbose logfile C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-09T08_23_19_508Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 5ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
28 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
29 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
30 timing idealTree:init Completed in 585ms
31 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 11ms
32 silly idealTree buildDeps
33 silly fetch manifest react-native-tesseract-ocr@*
34 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-tesseract-ocr 1723ms (cache revalidated)
36 silly fetch manifest react@16.13.1
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react 117ms (cache revalidated)
38 silly fetch manifest react-native@0.64.2
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native 17ms (cache hit)
40 silly fetch manifest react@17.0.1
41 timing idealTree Completed in 2490ms
42 timing command:i Completed in 2501ms
43 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
43 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1398:25)
43 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1391:30)
43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1343:23)
43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:950:11)
43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:216:7)
43 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
43 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:153:5)
43 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:159:5)
43 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:66:5)
44 verbose cwd D:\MobileDev\EI\ei-platform\EIPlatform
45 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
46 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "react-native-tesseract-ocr"
47 verbose node v16.15.0
48 verbose npm  v8.5.5
49 error code ERESOLVE
50 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
51 error
52 error While resolving: [1mEIPlatform[22m@[1m0.0.1[22m
52 error Found: [1mreact[22m@[1m16.13.1[22m[2m[22m
52 error [2mnode_modules/react[22m
52 error   [1mreact[22m@"[1m16.13.1[22m" from the root project
52 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m^16.8.1[22m" from [1mreact-native-tesseract-ocr[22m@[1m2.0.3[22m[2m[22m
52 error   [2mnode_modules/react-native-tesseract-ocr[22m
52 error     [1mreact-native-tesseract-ocr[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
52 error
52 error Could not resolve dependency:
52 error [35mpeer[39m [1mreact[22m@"[1m17.0.1[22m" from [1mreact-native[22m@[1m0.64.2[22m[2m[22m
52 error [2mnode_modules/react-native[22m
52 error   [1mreact-native[22m@"[1m0.64.2[22m" from the root project
52 error   [35mpeer[39m [1mreact-native[22m@"[1m>=0.60.0-rc.0 <1.0.x[22m" from [1mreact-native-tesseract-ocr[22m@[1m2.0.3[22m[2m[22m
52 error   [2mnode_modules/react-native-tesseract-ocr[22m
52 error     [1mreact-native-tesseract-ocr[22m@"[1m*[22m" from the root project
52 error
52 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
52 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
52 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
52 error
52 error See C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
53 verbose exit 1
54 timing npm Completed in 2737ms
55 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1662711799733
56 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1662711799740
57 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1662711800337
58 verbose unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1662711800338
59 verbose code 1
60 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
60 error     C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-09T08_23_19_508Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried to install the package with --force command and it installs the package but it does not work as intended and throws error undefined recognize at command

```
TesseractOcr.recognize()
```

I have tried to remove the node_modules folder completely and reinstalling it but still no success.
I even tried to make a new fresh project and tried installing this package but i receive the same error.
Have done multiple searches online but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

first run your command then run this command

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: Hello
First I ran command npm i react-native-tesseract-ocr
The errors came,
then i ran your command react-native start --reset-cache
followed by my command and still the errors came